# Correct way to execute a Runnable after focus transfer

Tags: java, swing, focus

I want to transfer focus to a component and execute a `Runnable` when the component is focused. My problem is that the method `Component.requestFocusInWindow` don't grant me a direct focus transfer even if it returns true. I wrote this method:

```
public static boolean focusComponent(Component toFocus, Runnable afterFocus) {
    FocusAdapter fa = new FocusAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            if (afterFocus != null) {
                afterFocus.run();
            }
            e.getComponent().removeFocusListener(this);
        }
    };
    toFocus.addFocusListener(fa);
    boolean result = toFocus.requestFocusInWindow();
    if (result) {
        // to be safe when the requestFocusInWindow returns true but the component get no focus
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> toFocus.removeFocusListener(fa));
    } else {
        toFocus.removeFocusListener(fa);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is my code correct? May I probably remove `invokeLater` call or rewrite it without `invokeLater`?

Comment: Have you tried using `grabFocus()`? Please take a look at [Difference between requestFocusInWindow() and grabFocus()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680817/difference-between-requestfocusinwindow-and-grabfocus-in-swing)

Comment: @MohamadChaman-Motlagh `grabFocus` calls the same method as `requestFocusInWindow`. The only one difference, is that it allows to change window on focus change. So it also don't grant a direct focus change.

Comment: Focus issues are tricky. I think the `afterFocus.run()` should be wrapped in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`. This should guarantee the component has focus when the Runnable is executed.

Comment: @Sergiy Medvynskyy no idea about the reason for toggling with Focus, you can to try selectAll(incl. empty Document and It should be fired as last repaints from EDT), btw whats output from setFocusable(incl. JButton), to your question it must be inside invokeLater()

Comment: @camickr  I try to avoid the calls of `invokeLater` because they make application a liitle bit "unpredictable". When I use `invokeLater` too much, one time I need to call it twice to implement a feature (or more times). So I'll choose my current solution.